# Mesmo utilizando um semáforo, enfrento repetição de bloco. Por quê e como evitar?

Tags: python-3.x

Então, estou com um código que coloquei um semáforo, assim evitando sobreposição no print, porém noto algumas estranhas ocorrências de um mesmo **while**. Por quê isso acontece? Há como evitar?

```py
import threading
import time

sem = threading.Semaphore()
number = 0

def primeira():
    global number
    while True:
        number += 1        
        sem.acquire()
        print(f'P1: {number}')
        sem.release()
        time.sleep(1)


def segunda():
    global number
    while True:
        sem.acquire()
        number += 1
        print(f'P2: {number}')
        sem.release()
        time.sleep(1)


td1 = threading.Thread(target=primeira)
td2 = threading.Thread(target=segunda)

td1.start()
td2.start()

td1.join()
td2.join()
```

Percebo que ao rodar, as vezes o P1 ou P2 são executados/impressos duas vezes e mesmo assim eles mantêm a integridade da ordem dos números.

Exemplo:

```py
P1: 1
P2: 2
P1: 3
P2: 4  // Aqui
P2: 5  //
P1: 6
P2: 7
P1: 8  // Aqui
P1: 9  //
P2: 10
```

Percebo também, que ao diminuir o tempo de `sleep`, mais frequente esta repetição ocorre, mas nunca passa de **2 vezes**, como no exemplo. Por quê? Há como evitá-la de forma simples?

Comment: Só para esclarecer, você esperava que sempre alternaria uma thread para a outra?

Comment: Sim, exatamente isto: P1 -> P2 -> P1.... 
Estou vendo a documentação de ```asyncio locks```, parece ser o jeito 'correto' de fazer, mas não estou conseguindo aplicar.

Comment: Sim, em relação ao Lock é basicamente isso, sim, a premissa é que está errada. Não existe garantia na ordem de qual thread executará e adquirá o controle do Lock, assim P2 pode soltar o lock e imediatamente depois adquirí-lo novamente. Quem lida com isso é o sistema operacional e nem faz sentido querer definir a ordem de execução, pois se precisa manter a ordem, pode fazer na mesma thread